# Android opengl.Matrix class issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

Typical rotation formulas are (wiki)

[image]

Lets take, for example rotation around X-axis at 45 degrees. cos45 = sin45 = 0.707...

So the result matrix should be

[ 1          0     0            0 ]

| 0    0.707    -0.707    0 |

| 0    0.707    0.707    0 |

[ 0           0          0     1 ]

So I use android.opengl.Matrix

Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);

Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0, 45, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Then I watch result and it is:

[ 1          0     0            0 ]

| 0    0.707    -0.499    0 |

| 0    0.707    0.207    0 |

[ 0           0          0     1 ]

Explain please what is this? A bug? A feature? Or may be I miss some math and its equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different versions of `android.opengl.Matrix.rotateM`:

```
public static void rotateM (float[] m, int mOffset, float a, float x, float y, float z)
// Rotates matrix m in place by angle a (in degrees) around the axis (x, y, z)

public static void rotateM (float[] rm, int rmOffset, float[] m, int mOffset, float a, float x, float y, float z)
// Rotates matrix m by angle a (in degrees) around the axis (x, y, z)
```

It looks like you want to rotate it in place -- your source matrix and result matrix are the same float[] -- but you're using the call that reads from one matrix and writes to another.  Looking at the implementations of `rotateM`, it appears this is not supported.

Comment: Yes this indeed it is not supported: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/opengl/Matrix.java/?v=source Internally does a multriplyMM: "The same float array may be passed for result, lhs, and/or rhs. However, the result element values are undefined if the result elements overlap either the lhs or rhs elements."